# Issue with some simple exception handling using .hasNextInt() in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I'm creating an array list for a menu of food items which correspond to a number on a menu. Most of that is left out: my main issue is that the error message does not display for the first time the user does not enter an integer value. Nothing will show on the console after I press enter, but if I again enter something that isn't an integer it will work like it should and display the error message.

Edit: something else I should note is that earlier in the code I use the same scanner object so use .next() to clear it of the previous value it had.

```
        orderArray = new String[length];
        menuDisplay(); 
        int item; //the item number that user must enter
        for(int i=1; i<=length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please choose item #"+ i+": ");
            scan.next();
            while(!scan.hasNextInt()) //this while loop checks that an integer value has been entered
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer value from the above menu.");
                scan.next();
            }

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by you *"use .next() to clear it of the previous value it had."*? It sounds like the blank call to `next()` is the problem

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code including the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hasNextInt` check the *next* token, not the token just received, so always call `hasNextXxx()` *before* calling `nextXxx()`.

You'd also want to actually get the integer value and assign it to `item`.

Rearrange your code like this:

```
System.out.println("Please choose item #"+ i+": ");
while (!scan.hasNextInt()) //this while loop checks that an integer value has been entered
{
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer value from the above menu.");
    scan.next(); // skip bad token
}
item = scan.nextInt();
```